# When to use subresources in Rest API?

Tags: rest, api-design

This question is related to a simillar one posted on [RESTful design: when to use sub-resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488697/restful-design-when-to-use-sub-resources) but it doesnt mention this case.

I have this example

```
/cars/{carid}
{
"id": 1,
"brand": "something"
"engine":
{
"horse_power": 100,
"type": "hybrid"
}
}
```

What would be a proper reasoning that could help me decide if this example should be split into a sub-resource to look like this

```
/cars/{carid}
{
"id": 1,
"brand": "something"
}

/cars/{carid}/engine
"engine":
{
"horse_power": 100,
"type": "hybrid"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe splitting the main resource into multiple sub-resources makes sense if the main resource is a complex entity with many arrays and other related entities.

However, if you are concerned about performance issues, bear in mind that [*premature optimization is the root of all evil*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092/122966). You shouldn't optimize until you have a performance problem and you have proven that the performance problem comes from sending a large representation of the resources.

---

For the situation mentioned in the question, supporting a sub-resource like `/cars/{id}/engine` could be useful when replacing the whole engine of the car, as following:

```
PUT /cars/1/engine HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "horse_power" : 110,
  "type" : "eletric"
}
```

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
```

When requesting `/cars/1`, a full representation of the car, including the engine, would be returned:

```
GET /cars/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Accept: application/json
```

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id" : 1,
  "brand" : "something",
  "engine" : {
    "horse_power" : 110,
    "type" : "eletric"
  }
}
```

To return a partial representation of the resource, consider the approaches mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37457166/1426227).

When requesting `/cars/1/engine`, the representation of the engine would be returned:

```
GET /cars/1/engine HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Accept: application/json
```

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "horse_power" : 110,
  "type" : "eletric"
}
```

Comment: But this would also be possible with PUT /cars/1/HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "horse_power" : 110,
  "type" : "eletric"
}

Comment: I was looking for more rest related benefits when splitting resources other then cleaner code and less markup.

Comment: @mko When performing `PUT /cars/1`, you are expected to replace the target resource (in this situation, the car with the ID `1`) with the representation sent in the request payload.

Comment: exactly, so you could actually sent just engine such as {
  "horse_power" : 110,
  "type" : "eletric"
} in order to do a partial update on cars/1 or even {
  "horse_power" : 110,
} to just change the horse_power of the engine. I believe this is allowed by rest

Comment: @mko No. The `PUT` method means *replace*. When using `PUT`, the target resource must be fully replaced with the representation sent in the request payload. For partial updates, `PATCH` must be used.

Comment: does it make sense to use cars/{carsid} (with engine) for GET and cars/{carid}/engine for PUT?

Comment: @mko Depending on your requirements, you could support both `GET` and `PUT` for both `/cars/{id}` and `/cars/{id}/engine`. It's up to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136370/discussion-between-mko-and-cassio-mazzochi-molin).

Comment: @mko If my answer suits you, don't forget to accept it :)